# options menu action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons, overflow

Can anyone see why my help icon isn't showing in the action bar? I have pasted the relevant parts of my code below

Thank you

menu topline.xml:
`

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/gohome_id"
    android:title="Home"
    trial10:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/helpme_id"
    android:title="help"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_questionmark"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    trial10:showAsAction="always"
    />
```

`

styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
</style>

<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
    parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/logo3</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/leaflogo</item>

</style>
<style name="orangestyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/orange</item>
</style>'
```

This is in my activity java:

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.topline, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.gohome_id:
            gohome();
            break;

    }
    return true;

}
```

finally, my Manifest:

```
  <activity
        android:name=".test1"
        android:label="Test"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: is  go home visible ?

Comment: Yeah it is pushed into an overflow menu (3 dots). As is "help". Whilst "home" should be tucked away,  I want the question mark icon to appear on the bar itself.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/gohome_id"
    android:title="Home"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/helpme_id"
    android:title="help"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_questionmark"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    />
```

Comment: Its still pushing it into the overflow. Also the icon doesn't display

Comment: I am getting 'cannot resolve symbol null on android:showAsAction

Comment: sorry there was typo please check it now

Comment: try to remove  `android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"`  from activity

Comment: Now there's no bar there at all!

Comment: Now I suggest you to use new toolbar in support Lib rather than actionbar

Answer (score 0):

Did you put your item in a menu tag?

```
<menu ....>
    <item.../>
    <item.../>
</menu>
```

If yes, change trial10:showAsAction with app:showAsAction. Just alt enter if there's an error on app.
Also delete that order line from home item