# Missing Action Icons on Action Bar

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

I have read quite a few entries here, and also Android document on this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

I created a new app from Android Studio, set the minimum SDK (21) and target SDK (22) to Android 5 (I don't need backward compatibility).

This is my menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/undo"
          android:icon="@drawable/undo"
          android:title="@string/undo"
          app:showAsAction="always"
          />
    <item android:id="@+id/clear"
          android:title="@string/clear"/>
    ...
</menu>
```

This is my rather simple onCreate:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    paintView = (PaintView) findViewById(R.id.view);
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(Wearable.API).build();
}
```

I have tried both always and ifRoom, and make sure that undo drawable is done for every DPI, but the undo button refused to come on (tested on Nexus 4, which has enough space for at least a few icons...)!

My current solution is to use a customView with an imageButton and onClick (this works), but I would like to know what could be the issue.

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31356805/options-menu-action-bar/31356900#31356900

Comment: Thanks. I uses android:showAsAction="always" and it is marked as error as was suggested to use app:showAsAction and xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't using `AppCompatActivity` or anything built on top of it (such as the [Design Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)), then you don't need `app:showAsAction` - just use `android:showAsAction`.

You can add `tools:ignore="AppCompatResource"` if you want to ignore the lint error that comes along with ignoring AppCompat` and instead using the framework versions of everything (not recommended).

Comment: I just use whatever default Android Studio gave me when I set up the new project (and uses Android 5.0). If I use android:showAsAction, it was shown as error and suggested to use app:showAsAction.

Comment: Yep, Android Studio assumes you use [AppCompat](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat) and `AppCompatActivity` as it is the recommended pattern for all apps (it is much more difficult to build many of the Material design patterns even on 5.0+ devices without the Design Library, which does require AppCompat).

Comment: If I don't care about pre-5.0 compatibility, how do I remove AppCompat? Or alternately, if AppCompat is a must, then what's my problem/solution?

Comment: You can either make sure your activity extends `AppCompatActivity` and use a `Theme.AppCompat` theme (in which case `app:showAsAction` is correct) if you want to use AppCompat (and things like the Design Library which I would say is needed for many even 5.0+ apps) or use `android:showAsAction`, like the answer says. I've edited the answer to include how you would remove the lint error.

Comment: You got it right! I am probably not using AppCompatActivity, so when I switch to android:showAsAction it works!